# Can Checkstyle verify that a string value is equal to the class or file name?

Tags: java, android, proguard, static-analysis, checkstyle

I have an Android project where most classes define a string constant containing the class name, to be used as the tag parameter to the [`Log`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class methods. For example:

```
public final class MyFileReader
{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "MyFileReader";

    // rest of class
}
```

Is it possible to write a [CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) rule to check that any value defined in this way matches the name of the class (or the root of the filename)? Please bear in mind:

- Not every class will define a `LOG-TAG` value, but where they do it must match the class name.
- Unfortunately the value does need to be a string constant. It's not an option to use `MyFileReader.class.getSimpleName()`, as in a release build the class names are optimized by [ProGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting use case! I think you can get away without writing your own check by using [Checkstyle Addons](http://checkstyle-addons.thomasjensen.com/) (of which I am the maintainer). It provides a [LocationReference](http://checkstyle-addons.thomasjensen.com/latest/checks/misc.html#LocationReference) check that you can use.

After [enabling Checkstyle Addons](http://checkstyle-addons.thomasjensen.com/run.html#run-intellij), configure the check like this:

```xml
<module name="LocationReference">
    <property name="variableNames" value="LOG_TAG" />
    <property name="location" value="simpleclass"/>
</module>
```

Comment: Nailed it! That does exactly what I wanted. Thank you.